# Can I prevent TinyMCE setContent from stealing focus?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

When I use `setContent` on a TinyMCE editor, it sets the focus to that editor control.

```
var te = tinymce.get('my_id');
te.setContent('new contents');
```

Any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the source code (I haven't used tinymce), I cannot find anything that would set the focus but there are some events that are fired so I think this is worth giving a shot:

```
te.setContent( 'new contents', { no_events: true } );
```

Answer (score 1):

My current workaround:

- set the focus back to the button that was just clicked
- restore the scrollTop

Using jQuery:

```
var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

// setContent stuff...

$(this).focus();
$(document).scrollTop(scrollTop);
```